# Show and hide different forms using radio box

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have two radioboxes and two forms on my page. 
based on selected radiobox, related form should be visible.
I tried to solve this problem and I ended up with this code:

```
    `http://jsfiddle.net/3g6c4anf/1/`
```

But this code has two problems:
1- when you run the code, all checked events fires up and all form slides up and down.
2- I want to form1 be visible by default. i did not make it so.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have modified your HTML as follows:

```
<div>
     <h2>Select form</h2>

    <p>
        <label>
            <input type='radio' value="both" name="myRadio" data-bind='checked: myRadioChecked' />both</label>
        <label>
            <input type='radio' value="form1" name="myRadio" data-bind='checked: myRadioChecked' />Form1</label>
        <label>
            <input type='radio' value="form2" name="myRadio" data-bind='checked: myRadioChecked' />Form2</label>
    </p>
    <div id="form1" class="forms">
        <input type="text" value="input form1" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div id="form2" class="forms">
        <input type="text" value="input form2" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I have modified your javascript as follows:

```
var FormsModel = function () {
    this.myRadioChecked = new ko.observable();

    this.formToShow = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        $(".forms").slideUp();
        switch (e) {
            case "form1":
                $("#form1").slideDown();
                break;
            case "form2":
                $("#form2").slideDown();
                break;
            default:
                $(".forms").slideDown();
                break;
        }
    };

    this.myRadioChecked.subscribe(this.formToShow);   

};

ko.applyBindings(new FormsModel());
```

I have also changed the css:

```
.forms {
    /*display:none;*/
}
```

Find my updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3g6c4anf/12/